# inverse an oriented Graph

Tags: c++, graph

How can I reverse not transpose an oriented graph ?

```
 Graphe *Graphe::grapheInverse( void ){
     Graphe *r = new Graphe (_adjacences.size() );
      for (unsigned i = 0; i < _adjacences.size(); i++){
          for (unsigned j = 0; j < _adjacences[i]->size(); j++){
              //r->addArcs(j,i); this doesn't work
          }
      }
      return r;
  }
```

where _adjacences is : `vector< vector< int > * > _adjacences;`

and `addArcs` is:

```
void Graphe::addArcs( int a_sommet1, int a_sommet2 ){
    assert( 0 <= a_sommet1 && a_sommet1 < _adjacences.size() );
    assert( nullptr != _adjacences[a_sommet1] );
    _adjacences[a_sommet1]->push_back( a_sommet2 );
}
```

Example:

```
    Graphe g( 5 );
    g.addArcs( 0, 1 );
    g.addArcs( 0, 4 );
    g.addArcs( 1, 0 );
    g.addArcs( 1, 4 );
    g.addArcs( 2, 0 );
    g.addArcs( 2, 1 );
    g.addArcs( 2, 3 );
    g.addArcs( 2, 4 );
    g.addArcs( 4, 3 );
    g.addArcs( 4, 1 );

    // inversion du graphe :
    Graphe *r = g.grapheInverse();
```

My full code is as follows:

Graphe.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Graphe
{
private:
    vector< vector< int > * > _adjacences;
public:
    Graphe( void );
    Graphe( int a_nbSommet );
    virtual ~Graphe( void );

    int nbSommet( void ) const;
    vector< int > * adjacences( int a_sommet );
    void addArcs( int a_sommet1, int a_sommet2 );

    Graphe * grapheInverse( void );

    friend ostream & operator <<( ostream &, Graphe const & );
};
```

Graphe.cpp

```
#include "Graphe.hpp"

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

Graphe::Graphe( void )
{
}


Graphe::Graphe( int a_nbSommet ): _adjacences( a_nbSommet ){
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < a_nbSommet; ++ i ){
        _adjacences[i] = new vector< int >();
    }
}


Graphe::~Graphe( void )
{
}


void Graphe::addArcs( int a_sommet1, int a_sommet2 ){
    assert( 0 <= a_sommet1 && a_sommet1 < _adjacences.size() );
    assert( nullptr != _adjacences[a_sommet1] );
    _adjacences[a_sommet1]->push_back( a_sommet2 );
}


int Graphe::nbSommet( void ) const{
    return _adjacences.size();
}


vector< int > *Graphe::adjacences( int a_sommet ){
    assert( 0 <= a_sommet && a_sommet < _adjacences.size() );
    return _adjacences[ a_sommet ];
}


Graphe *Graphe::grapheInverse( void ){
    Graphe *r = new Graphe (_adjacences.size() );
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < _adjacences.size(); i++)
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < _adjacences[i]->size(); j++ )
            r->addArcs ((*_adjacences[i])[j],i); 
    return r;
}


ostream &operator <<( ostream & a_out, Graphe const & a_graphe ){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < a_graphe._adjacences.size(); ++ i ){
        a_out << i << " : ";
        for( j = 0; j < a_graphe._adjacences[i]->size(); ++ j ){
            if( 0 != j ){
                a_out << ", ";
            }
            a_out << ( a_graphe._adjacences[i]->at(j) );
        }
        a_out << endl;
    }

    return a_out;
}
```

my main

```
#include "Graphe.hpp"


#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main( int argn, char * argv[] ){
    // construction of the graph :
    Graphe g( 5 );
    g.addArcs( 0, 1 );
    g.addArcs( 0, 4 );
    g.addArcs( 1, 0 );
    g.addArcs( 1, 4 );
    g.addArcs( 2, 0 );
    g.addArcs( 2, 1 );
    g.addArcs( 2, 3 );
    g.addArcs( 2, 4 );
    g.addArcs( 4, 3 );
    g.addArcs( 4, 1 );

    // inversion of the graph :
    Graphe *r = g.grapheInverse();

    // printing the both lists for verification
    cout << g << endl;
    cout << *r << endl;
}
```

this gives me:

```
g:
0 : 1, 4
1 : 0, 4
2 : 0, 1, 3, 4
3 : 
4 : 3, 1

r:
0 : 1, 2
1 : 0, 2, 4
2 : 
3 : 2, 4
4 : 0, 1, 2
```

Comment: 1. why are you using pointers rather than normal objects, 2. why is the adjacency list a  vector of pointers, i.e. why `vector<vector<int>*> _adjacences` instead of `vector<vector<int>> _adjacences`

Comment: because in my main i have some tests to run that use those pointers. it still gives the same results anyways

Comment: Avoid owning bare pointers.

Comment: I see that you've added some code now. Good. It's not minimal though. Here's [my version](https://godbolt.org/z/3nPa3q) of your program. Since it's all in one big chunk, everyone can copy/compile it easily. I've removed everything that you don't use and fixed all warnings about signness etc. I've removed `( void )` in the argument sepc to functions that I told you before you don't need and I return the inverted graph by value (why return a pointer?!). It still has terrible memory leaks of course. What compilator options do you use? You need to increase the warning level and take care of all.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you're amazing my friend, it works and I compiled it with g++, it works as intended. I can't thank you enough :'D

Comment: Here's the same program without memory leaks: [not a pointer in sight](https://godbolt.org/z/MTG1Ee).

You're welcome, but I don't think it works, does it? It _should_ do the same thing as your version since I didn't touch the logic. It's just cleaner code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it works sir just as intended, and yeah there is not a single pointer as I can see lol. thanks again TED

Comment: I didn't do that much really. It was 1201ProgramAlarm who fixed the logic - I just came in with a broom.  You're welcome for the cleaning service anyway. Removing pointer stuff and fixing warnings can certainly have some positive side effects :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making the reverse list, you don't want to use the index in the original list as the source vertex, you need to derefence the list.  So you'll want to use

```
r->addArcs((*_adjacences[i])[j],i);
```

There are better ways to write that function (like range-based for loops).

Comment: how can i overrun this ```error: no viable conversion from 'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >' to 'int'```, it's because of that ```vector<vector<int>*>``` ?

Comment: @azaiz I've updated the code to dereference the internal vector before taking the subscript.

Comment: @azaiz The problem with not providing a [mcve] with example input and the expected output is that people can't check if their answers are actually doing that the asker wants.

Comment: @azaiz I took your code, my fix, and added in lots of other code to enable me to compile and run your code, including adding a print function. I get the expected transposition. Edit your question to include your code that we can compile and run, as the problem in your comment seems to be in code that you do not show.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm alright sir, I'll edit it right away