# How to reverse an Adjacency list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, adjacency-list

Let's say my adjacency list is as follows:

```
0 : 1
1 : 0
```

it's reverse should be empty because there is two arcs in the initial list:

```
0:
1:
```

or

```
0 : 1
1 :
```

becomes

```
0 : 
1 : 0
```

another example:

```
0 : 
1 :
```

becomes

```
0 : 1
1 : 0
```

last example

```
0 : 1, 4
1 : 0, 4
2 : 0, 1, 3, 4
3 : 
4 : 3, 1
```

becomes

```
0 : 2, 3
1 : 2, 3
2 : 
3 : 0, 1, 2, 4
4 : 0, 2
```

is there an algorithm to do this ?

```
Graphe *Graphe::grapheInverse( void ){
    Graphe *r = new Graphe (_adjacences.size() );
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < _adjacences.size(); i++)
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < _adjacences[i]->size(); j++ )
            if ( (*_adjacences[i])[j] == 1 ) // or 0 or 2 or 3 or 4 or ... like last example
                //r->addArcs( i, (*_adjacences[i])[j] ); //adds an arc from A to B
            
    return r;
}
```

Comment: How is this different from [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63382179/inverse-an-oriented-graph)?

Comment: this one is with more examples and less code to read

Comment: You didn't clearly state what you mean by reversing the graph. Surely it's not in line with e.g. https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/reverse-the-directed-graph/ . From the examples it seems that you want all possible arcs not present in the original graph, and excluding self-pointing "loop" arcs.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff yes what was available in initial graph will be removed and what's not available will be available in the reversed graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just invert the adjacency matrix.

Wherever you have a 0, replace it with a 1, and vice versa. Only exclude the diagonal, always put a 0 there.